# A group of order 2295 is nilpotent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, nilpotent-groups

Good evening, first of all sorry for my bad english and for my bad knowledge of algebra; so I need help to solve this exercise please.

I want to show my idea (probably wrong):

like in another Answer in this forum, I know that a group $G^*$ of order $765$ is abelian; so I observe that $|G|=|G^*|\cdot 3$ and the quotient $G/C_3$, that has order $765$, is an abelian group; I think that $C_3$ is the minimal subgroup of $G$ with this property, then I may assert that $G'=C_3$?

If is correct, I suspect that $G$ is metabelian but for say this, I need to show that the down central series defined by:

$G=\Gamma_0 \supseteq \Gamma_1\supseteq\ldots\ldots\supseteq\Gamma_n=e$

with $\Gamma_i=[G,\Gamma_{i-1}]$

has lenght $2$; so is like:

$G\supseteq G'\supseteq e$

or

$G\supseteq C_3 \supseteq e$

so I'm not able to show that $[G,C_3]=e$ and hence $C_3=G'=Z(G)$...

Please UNDERLINE mercilessly all my mistakes.

With regard,

Leonardo Ventura.

Comment: Welcome to m.se. When you say things like "like in another Answer in this forum", it's much clearer to provide a hyperlink.

Comment: Sorry, in fact wasn't in this forum;
this is the link: https://www.coursehero.com/file/p63k84/Let-G-be-a-group-of-order-765-9-5-17-We-need-to-prove-that-G-is-abelian-It-is/

With regard,

Leonardo Ventura.

Comment: Right from the start, what does $G/C_3$ even mean? How do you know that $G$ has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $C_3$?

Comment: A finite group is nilpotent if and only if all its Sylow subgroups are normal, so I suggest approaching that way. As in the link you provided, start with the large primes. For example, the same method as there gives that the Sylow $17$-subgroup is normal. The automorphism group of $C_{17}$ has order $16$, which is coprime to the order of the group, so that in fact it is central (by the NC-theorem). So it remains to show that the quotient (of order 5*27) is nilpotent. I leave that to you...